# Where can I order techelet and have them fully tied and prepared?

Tags: product-recommendation, tzitzis, techeles

Of course, the most common answer is [Ptil Tekhelet](https://www.tekhelet.com/).

Is there anywhere else? I live in the New York area and have called a few local Judaica stores who have told me they can sell the strings to me but do not tie it. I personally cannot tie them, and I was curious if anyone has orderd Techelet from any local tyers in New York or online and have them delivered or picked up fully made.

P.s. I am not looking for someone to *only* tie them. I would ideally like to order it in one shot from someone who has the beged, the strings, and will prepare them. Thanks!

Comment: For the right price an "only tier" may be willing to order the stuff for you too

Comment: Which shitta do you plan on tying

Comment: If you're in New York there is according to here https://yivoencyclopedia.org/article.aspx/Izhbits-Radzin_Hasidic_Dynasty a strong concentration of Radzyner chassidim based in New York. Owing to the fact that they have the minhag to wear techeiles it might make sense to get in touch?

Comment: i know a guy in toronto who sometimes visits new york to tie but you can also order from him. i’d get in touch with him thru his website here: https://bluefringes.com/ then of course there’s ben’s tallit shop he always has good prices

Comment: concerning my comment above rafi hecht of bluefringes is very ehrlich and very knowledgeable on all different techeiles issues, halacha and tying methods i’d really recommend speaking with him he also runs a great group on facebook for techeiles enthusiasts

Comment: @sam i'm not sure yet. i first want to find someone or somewhere to order from. if they do not tie a specific shita then I would look into whatever they have.

Comment: @ezra do I contact Rafi through the bluefringes website?

Answer (score 1):

See https://bluefringes.com. Also, for lively discussion see https://www.facebook.com/groups/techeiles .

Comment: Thank you, Rafi. Does that only work for people in Ontario? Can I order some to have them delivered here in New York?

Comment: Rafi, you might want to include a caveat that bluefringes.com is your website (I know it, you know it, but it's just good policy IMO)